# mysql server shuts down on its own every 5 minutes

Tags: mysql, wordpress, ubuntu

I'm running a Wordpress Blog in a 512mb RAM Ubuntu 12.04 Server. The blog i'm working with has a considerable amount of traffic.

At first, the mysql server shuts down every time I enter the dashboard (sometimes I don't even reach wp-login.php). I thought that by disabling the wp plugins directory temporarily should do the trick, thinking that a plugin may be causing it. When I did just that, mysql doesn't shutdown anymore...for just a while. After 5 to 10 minutes, the problem occurs again and mysql shutdowns by itself. The only good thing that action did was to prolong the life of the mysql server before it shuts down by itself.

This is my error log from `/var/log/mysql/error.log` . It consists of several blocks of these:

```
131218 12:39:34 [Warning] Using unique option prefix myisam-recover instead of myisam-recover-options is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use the full name instead.
131218 12:39:34 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
131218 12:39:34 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
131218 12:39:34 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
131218 12:39:34 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3.4
131218 12:39:34 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
InnoDB: mmap(137363456 bytes) failed; errno 12
131218 12:39:34 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
131218 12:39:34 InnoDB: Fatal error: cannot allocate memory for the buffer pool
131218 12:39:34 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
131218 12:39:34 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
131218 12:39:34 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
131218 12:39:34 [ERROR] Aborting

131218 12:39:34 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete
```

Research points that I may indeed be lacking in memory but i'm trying to avoid upgrading not until I confirmed that that is the only solution.

Any ideas? TIA

Comment: 512 MB RAM is likely to be way too little for a high-traffic WordPress blog. You are, indeed, running out of memory. You'll want to look at `top` to find out what exactly is taking up RAM - chances are it's MySQL and a bunch of Apache workers.

Comment: 512MB of RAM? For a high traffic server? I would not even use that to develop on nevermind production. Upgrade that is the only solution.

Comment: Upgrade worked perfectly. Thanks guys!